# $ is not defined while implementing angular data-tables in ionic 3 angular 4 application

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-datatables

I am new to ionic. I am creating one simple application in ionic 3 angular 4. In this while implementing the angular datatable. I got the following error.

vendor.js:1822 ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

I don’t know what I am doing wrong. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Initially I have installed all of the following libraries using command prompt,

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install datatables.net --save
npm install datatables.net-dt --save
npm install angular-datatables --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/datatables.net --save-dev
```

After that I have included the dependencies - scripts(jquery.dataTables.css) and styles(jquery.js,jquery.dataTables.js) attributes in the angular-cli.json. please find my complete angular-cli.json file below,

angular-cli.json:

```
{
“$schema”: “./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json”,
“project”: {
“name”: “sample-datatables”
},
“apps”: [
{
“root”: “src”,
“outDir”: “dist”,
“assets”: [
“assets”,
“favicon.ico”
],
“index”: “index.html”,
“main”: “main.ts”,
“polyfills”: “polyfills.ts”,
“test”: “test.ts”,
“tsconfig”: “tsconfig.app.json”,
“testTsconfig”: “tsconfig.spec.json”,
“prefix”: “app”,
“styles”: [
“styles.css”,
“…/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css”,
“…/node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css”,
“…/node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css”
],
“scripts”: [
“…/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js”,
“…/node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js”,
“…/node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js”,
“…/node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js”,
“…/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js”
],
“environmentSource”: “environments/environment.ts”,
“environments”: {
“dev”: “environments/environment.ts”,
“prod”: “environments/environment.prod.ts”
}
}
],
“e2e”: {
“protractor”: {
“config”: “./protractor.conf.js”
}
},
“lint”: [
{
“project”: “src/tsconfig.app.json”,
“exclude”: “/node_modules/”
},
{
“project”: “src/tsconfig.spec.json”,
“exclude”: “/node_modules/”
},
{
“project”: “e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json”,
“exclude”: “/node_modules/”
}
],
“test”: {
“karma”: {
“config”: “./karma.conf.js”
}
},
“defaults”: {
“styleExt”: “css”,
“component”: {}
}
}
```

todoList.html:

```
 <ion-header>

      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>To-do List</ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>

    </ion-header>


    <ion-content padding>



          <table datatable class="row-border hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Foo</td>
          <td>Bar</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Someone</td>
          <td>Youknow</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Iamout</td>
          <td>Ofinspiration</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Yoda</td>
          <td>Skywalker</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Patrick</td>
          <td>Dupont</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>Barack</td>
          <td>Obama</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>François</td>
          <td>Holland</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>Michel</td>
          <td>Popo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>Chuck</td>
          <td>Norris</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>Simon</td>
          <td>Robin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>Louis</td>
          <td>Lin</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>Zelda</td>
          <td>Link</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


    </ion-content>
```

In app.module.ts I have imported the Datatable module as follows,

```
import { DataTablesModule } from ‘angular-datatables’;

@NgModule({
.
.
.
imports: [
DataTablesModule
]
})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u show me the place you are using $ ?

Comment: I didn't use $ anywhere.

Comment: I guess the relative path is wrong, try with two dots `"../"` instead of  `".../"`

Comment: I angular-cli.json it is two dots only. Here it seems llike three dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because jquery is not included to your project.

1. Check if the links you specified in the .angular.cli.json are correct for the scripts.

   `"../node_modules/  "`
2. You can simple include the jquery with a script tag in your index html.

   `<script src="jquery_cdn_link"> </script>`

---

If the above does not solve it, feel free to comment I am here.

Comment: OP has included jquery in `angular.cli.json`

Comment: Check it in your browser dev-tools if really did .

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The issue has been resolved after adding the jquery in index.html page using script tags. you save my day thank you once again @bereket gebredingle